# Screen timeout not happening while app running for longer

Tags: ios

I have kept my iphone with app open for few minutes , but screen didnt get timout and didint get locked.
How can we lock screen when app is idle for few minutes .
What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the app from Xcode the device enters in debug mode then it won't get locked.

1. Install the app from Xcode, remove the cable wait a while and check if the phone is automatically locked. Don't run the app from Xcode.
2. Check your code for the occurrences of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`
3. Make sure your auto lock configuration in the settings app is not set to "Never".

Comment: Its not getting lock on device

Comment: @AnshikaGupta An app can keep the auto lock off if is using the following line: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` so check your code if you have that.

Comment: I commented this code , still not working. My iphone has 1 min screen timeout. it didnt get locked

Comment: Is your phone **unplugged** from the mac? It  is important to unplug it, otherwise Xcode will not let the device auto lock.